# C socket atomic non-blocking read

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, nonblocking, epoll

I'm implementing a TCP/IP server application which uses epoll in edge-triggered mode and does non-blocking socket operations. The clients are using simple blocking operations without epoll.

I don't see how "atomic reads" can be implemented on the server side. To explain what I mean about "atomic read", see this example with simple blocking operations:

- Both the client and the server are using 64K buffers. (On application level. They don't change the kernel level socket buffers.)
- Client writes 12K data with a single write operation.
- Server reads it. In this case it always reads the whole 12K when the buffers are the same. So it can't read only the half of it. This is what I call "atomic".

But in the case of epoll + non-blocking operations this can happen:

- Both the client and the server are using 64K buffers. (On application level. They don't change the kernel level socket buffers.)
- Client writes 12K data with a single write operation.
- 6K arrives to the server
- epoll tells the application that data arrived to the socket
- the application reads the 6K into the buffer using a non-blocking operation.
- When repeating the read, it returns EAGAIN / EWOULDBLOCK.

In this case the read is not "atomic". It is not guarantied that when the data was written with a single write operation, then the read will return the whole, in one piece.

Is it possible to know when the data is partial? I know that one solution is to always append the data size to the beginning, or another could be to always close and re-open the connection, but I don't wanna do these: because I think the kernel must know that not the full "package" (how is that unit called BTW?) arrived, since it guaranties atomicity for the blocking operations.

Many thanks!

Comment: You generally need to write all I/O in a *loop* and maintain your own buffers.

Comment: If your call to `read` on the socket didn't return `0` then you can expect there to be more data which you can capture in an event loop.

Comment: In binary transmission, it is common to add a delimiter, such as start of transmission and end of transmission. In text transmissions, syntax checking is your friend. If you are transmitting json strings, you can parse the json string to determine if it's complete or not.

Comment: jacob: I know that, but you can't decide if you are reading a message from the beginning or from its half. (Multiple messages are sent in the same connection.)

Comment: alvits: but it seems that in case of blocking operations you don't need to do that, but TCP/IP keeps your data together, which was sent by a single write. Or that's not true?

Comment: You'll have to maintain individual buffers that you're appending to for each client; and when you read some delimiter or if you're using a state machine to parse the buffer into a structure and reach the final state you can expect there to be no more data.

Comment: Kerrek SB: could you please explain that a bit further? Of course everything happens in loops, using buffers, so I don't understand your point.

Comment: `but TCP/IP keeps your data together, which was sent by a single write. Or that's not true?` No that is not true. Only the order is guaranteed, not the segmentation.

Comment: TCP provides no built-in message boundaries, they have to be implemented at the application level. A message can be split up into arbitrary segments during transmission.

Comment: TCP doesn't guarantee atomicity for the blocking version, either.

Comment: Ah thank you now I understand. The operations in the blocking case just only seem to be atomic, because we have arbitrary time to wait until it finishes. Or is it possible that a blocking read returns 6K in the first case?

Comment: Reads *are* atomic, and can be non-blocking, but neither appears to be what you're actually talking about here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is stream based and not message oriented. Even in case of blocking socket, you cannot be guaranteed that what the application sends would go as is on the wire in one go. TCP will decide its own course.

So, it is up to the application to do "atomic" read of it wishes. For example:

The application protocol should dictate that the message should be prepended by the length bytes. The length bytes inform the peer the size of the application data of interest. Of course, the application should be aware of when the two byte length indicator begins.

> [2 byte msg length][Data bytes of interest]

Based on this information the application doing read should take action. It should be polling the socket until it receives all bytes as indicated by the msg length bytes. Only then process the data.

If you need "atomic" read and not partial read you can use MSG_PEEK flag in `recv`. This shall not remove the data from the socket buffer. Application peeks into the socket, see if required number of data is in socket buffer based on return value.

> `ret = recv(sd, buf, MAX_CALL_DATA_SIZE, MSG_PEEK);`

Comment: I would accept it, but I have no karma for it ;) Although you could add this too: "Your presumption about the blocking case was not correct: for example the server can read only 4K with that blocking read and then return."

Comment: NP! Good luck for more reputation. And do remember to accept ;-)

Comment: If the answer was useful, possible to upvote/accept?